# Visual Studio opens different solution other than current solution while running it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, web-development-server

I have two Different Solutions.Lets say Solution A and Solution B. I opened and run Solution A and Solution B in `Visual Studio 2013` many times(Both contains ASP.NET MVC web site as startup project).But I encountered a strange behavior of `Visual Studio 2013`.That is if I open and run Solution A in `Visual Studio 2013` it opens Solution B 's start up project which is also a website.I am confused how it can be possible.

Comment: I'd check the SLN and project files and see if there are any dodgy paths or references

Comment: I did that @iwayneo. it worked normally before i put my machine idle to near one hour. then when i start and run the solution this occurred. I stopped and run IIS express in my taskbar also. But same result .

Comment: Check the path to the application in ISS - is it mapped to the correct folder?

Comment: I didn't host the website. It is local IIS   i did mention. In that case yes it maps with the correct folder.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced such behavior. In my case it has happened because of the same application names. For some reasons IIS remembered my previous web application. You can try to restart IIS.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of things happen very rarely as  I know.
Sometime this kind of things happens with the Visual Studio when working on several projects on same time or when you open many projects , debug and run them together and close some of them.

So try by closing the Visual Studio and Restarting it. If it's still happens restart your machine and check.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into Start Options in Web Site Property Pages Dialog Box. If you're using a custom server(which is most likely IIS), you need to change the Base URL according to the virtual directory that has been set for each website in the Web Server .  [image]